# Uso de $unwind sobre propiedades de objeto

Tags: mongodb, nosql

¿Es posible utilizar `$unwind` sobre las propiedades de un objeto al hacer una consulta con `agregation` en MongoDB v3?

Necesito extraer los controles que cumplan con cierta condicion en cada objeto del array de objetos de cada clave de areas. La cuestion es que las claves en areas pueden variar. Puede tener dos claves como en el ejemplo, pero en otros casos puede tener hasta 3 y 4 cuatro claves.

```
{
   id: 12,
   name: "adsdf",
   areas: {
      clave1: [
         {
            "controles": ["valor1","valor2","valor3"]          
         },
         {
            "controles": ["valor4","valor5","valor6"]          
         }
      ],
      clave2: [
         {
            "controles": ["valor7","valor8","valor9"]          
         },
         {
            "controles": ["valor10","valor11","valor12"]          
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

Un resultado seria algo asi por ejemplo:

```
{
   id: 12,
   name: "adsdf",
   areas: {
      clave1: [
         {
            "controles": ["valor1","valor3"]          
         },
         {
            "controles": ["valor5"]          
         }
      ],
      clave2: [
         {
            "controles": ["valor9"]          
         },
         {
            "controles": ["valor12"]
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

Comment: ¿Puedes mostrar un ejemplo de lo que quieres lograr? Para entender a qué te refieres con "propiedades de un objeto"

Comment: Acabo de editar la pregunta.

Comment: Pero no has especificado cuál es la condición, solo has puesto el ejemplo y el resultado esperado pero no las condiciones o reglas que deben aplicar en tu query

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MongoDB es un sistema en el cual no hay un esquema predefinido para los objetos de una colección. Es muy probable y, además muy recomendable, que los documentos de una colección en particular tengan una estructura similar. Si se da el caso de que existen documentos en la misma colección con distinta estructura deberemos gestionarlo en la lógica de la aplicación.

En tu caso en particular, el campo "areas" difiere de un documento a otro, puesto que contiene distintos campos: clave 1, clave2 para un documento; clave 1, clave 2, clave 3 para otro documento; etc.

La naturaleza del propio campo conlleva a pensar que debería ser de tipo array, puesto que contiene un nº aleatorio de elementos y que, además, son del mismo tipo.

Por otra parte, y como ya ha comentado César Bustíos, el comando `$unwind` de aggregation framework solo trabaja sobre arrays.

Dicho esto, una aproximación para solucionar tu problema puede consistir en realizar una búsqueda de los nombres de los campos que contiene el subdocumento "areas" utilizando [`mapReduce`](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/reference/command/mapReduce/) y a partir de los resultados, buscar el valor de dichos campos por programación. El siguiente ejemplo puede ayudarte a obtener los nombres de dichos campos:

```
mr = db.mapreduce.mapReduce(
    function() { for (var key in this.areas) {emit(key, null)}},
    function(key, stuff) {return null;},
    { out:"my_collection" + "_keys" }
)

db[mr.result].distinct("_id")
```

Comment: Excelente tu comentario. Y si debería ser un arreglo. En eso tienes toda la razón. Gracias.

Comment: Gracias por la apreciación!

Answer (score 2):

En la documentación de [`$unwind`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) está muy claro lo que puedes lograr. Usando ese mismo ejemplo, si tienes una colección `inventario`:

```
{ "_id" : 1, "item" : "ABC1", sizes: [ "S", "M", "L"] }
```

Usando `$unwind` puedes obtener un documento por cada elemento del array `sizes`:

```
db.inventario.aggregate( [ { $unwind : "$sizes" } ] )
```

Te arrojará como resultado:

```
{ "_id" : 1, "item" : "ABC1", "sizes" : "S" }
{ "_id" : 1, "item" : "ABC1", "sizes" : "M" }
{ "_id" : 1, "item" : "ABC1", "sizes" : "L" }
```

Es como hacer un "explode" al array `sizes`.

Comment: Excelente, muchas gracias. Con esto me queda claro que $unwind solo puede usado con arrays y no sobre las propiedades de un objeto. Muchas gracias.